# How do I force a page break in plain TeX?

Tags: tex

My apologies if this seems like a very newb question, but my attempts at directly googling for this seems to suffer a great deal of interference from TeX help pages, and I do not have a TeX reference book handy.

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Thanks! I had not realized that there was a special stackexchange for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I borrowed a book from a classmate, it seems this works reasonably well for me.

```
\vfil \break
```

Answer (score 1):

\clearpage should do the trick, even if figures or tables are included.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in plain

Comment: `\clearpage` is defined in LaTeX (only), and will not work (is an undefined macro) in plain TeX.